# How to add TabControl content as button dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I am working on a project where I want to add button in content property of TabControl in WPF.

I tried lot many ways but I failed.

This is the code Example :

1. XAML File
2. c# File

**1. XAML File**

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Name="DynamicTab">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

**2. C# File**

```
foreach(DataContextClass glist in groupsList)
{
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

    tab.Header = glist.ItemGroup;
    DynamicTab.Items.Add(tab);
    itemsList = itemsDALObj.ItemsGroupWise(glist.ItemGroup);
    for(int i =0 ; i<itemsList.Count;i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = "Button" + (i + 1);
        b.Content = itemsList[i].ItemName;
        b.Height = 80;
        b.Width = 100;
        tab.Content = sp;
        sp.Children.Add(b);
     }
};
```

I tried following options:

1. By adding stackpanel, Grid, Button in `<DataTemplate>` of `<TabControl.ContentTemplate>`.
2. By adding Dynamic Grid and in that Grid I add Dynamic Button.
3. Many other ways also which I am not able to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace in `XAML` instead of `<TabControl.ContentTemplate>` replace it with `<TabControl.DataContext>` and that's the solution it takes me hours to find this little mistake.

```
<TabControl.DataContext>
     <DataTemplate>

     </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.DataContext>
```

The above is the change in XAML part.

Answer (score 0):

A `TabControl` is designed around the idea that the only controls that will be added to it are `TabItem` controls.
You can in fact, add other controls directly to the parent `TabControl` object, but when you do, it automatically creates an implicit `TabItem` anyway to hold those objects.

For instance, if you add two `Button` controls directly to the `TabControl`, two implicit `TabItem` controls are created, one to hold each `Button`:

```
<TabControl>
  <Button/>
  <Button/>
</TabControl>
```

This works, but is very much the wrong way to go about it.

To properly add content to a `TabControl`, first create a `TabItem`.  Add your other controls to the `TabItem`, and then add the `TabItem` to the `TabControl`.  (You can add the `TabItem` to the `TabControl` first if you want, it doesn't really matter)

In XAML:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="This is the label for the tab item.">
    <Button Content="My Button"/>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In code (assuming a pre-existing TabControl):

```
        TabItem ti = new TabItem();
        ti.Header = "Tab Header Text";
        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.Content = "Button Text";
        ti.Content = bt;
        myTabControl.Items.Add(ti);
```

A `TabControl`, like all WPF controls is a container.  It can hold multiple objects, but all of those objects are actually `TabItem` objects.  The `TabItem` control can only hold one object, so if you want it to contain more than just the `Button`, you have to add a different container to the `TabItem` first; like a `Grid` or `StackPanel`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stewbob but i find the solution. i have to replace <TabControl.ContentTemplate> with <TabControl.DataContext> Thats it.